# run vim buffer content through js-beautify without having to save the file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

This vim script saves the current file and runs it through js-beautify every time I leave `insert` mode and return to `normal` mode.

I want to make it more efficient by running the buffer content directly through js-beautify without having to save the file first, the write events let to a noticeable lag.

```
function! TidyAndResetCursor ()
    let cursor_pos = getpos('.')
    :w
    %!js-beautify %
    :w
    call setpos('.', cursor_pos)
endfunction


augroup JSTidy
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertLeave *.js  :call TidyAndResetCursor()
augroup END
```

A second issue is that sometimes (e.g. during `undo`) the `cursor_pos` resets to the first line in the document, maybe because the save cursor position no longer exists. It should jump back to the closest existing one instead of defaulting to the first line.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you just want `%!js-beautify -`  which would replace your current buffer.  Won't be saved to disk until you explicitly write it though.  The dash filename just means stdin to js-beautify.

Comment: see below, my js-beautify doesn't like the `-` input, it literally searches for a file named `-`, not sure how to fix that..

Answer (score 1):

This command [from my own config](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/lang-javascript/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim#L46) will format the given lines (whole buffer by default) with `js-beautify`, using the current `shiftwidth`, and restore the cursor position:

```
" reformat selection
command! -buffer -range=% Format let b:winview = winsaveview() |
  \ execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!js-beautify -f - -j -B -s " . &shiftwidth |
  \ call winrestview(b:winview)
```

Usage:

```
:Format        " format entire buffer
:3,15Format    " format given lines
```

See `$ js-beautify --help` for the command-line options.

Comment: Thank you very much! My js-beautify doesn't like the `-` input it complains `cat index.js | js-beautify -f -
Unable to open path "/home/user/-"` what is going on?